# Is it possible to list members who have joined a server at a certain date?

Tags: discord.js

So I'm just wondering if this is possible. Like, list all the members who joined your server before/after/at a certain date?

Comment: Each `GuildMember` in your server has a [`joinedAt`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=joinedAt) property.